# Plesk - Forward mails to gmail or fetch directly with POP3 in gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, plesk, pop3, mail-server

Apart from creating a few websites and using it for my own domain to receive my mails, I haven't done much with plesk. When setting up the server, a friend helped me and suggested to me back then (3 or 4 years ago) to use the forward functionality provided by plesk to forward all mail to my gmail address. In gmail i just added my mail-address in the "send mail as" list so I can also send my mails from there.

I'm just wondering now if there is any reason why I shouldn't just let gmail directly check my mail-inbox via POP3.

Sorry, I'm really new to all this mail-server stuff, but I would like to get some input from some more experienced users if there are any security concerns with any of those methods or if it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with pop3 is that you download all mails from your mail-server itself. So the mails were retrieve and were downloaded from the server at the time. This can be a problem if you use a mail-client and store all mails there. In this case you're not able to retrieve your mails at the webmail for example, because the mails are stored in the client.

I would recommend to use IMAP so you can check your mails from the plesk-server at your mobile-phone, mail-client or webmail.